# Sending get request through NodeJS while passing a custom cookie & cookie value

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have tried http, https, superagent, and the requestify packages for nodejs.
None of them seem to work for passing cookies (or I am just doing it wrong)
Any ways here is my code.

```
var request = require('request')
var cookieJar = request.jar();

const req = request.defaults({
    jar: cookieJar
})

var url = 'https://roblox.com/mobileapi/userinfo'
var input = 'CookieValueHere' // obviously this isnt the real value im passing.

req.get({
    url : url,
    headers : {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        ".ROBLOSECURITY": input
    }, 
    (e,r,b) => {
        if (e) console.error(e)
        console.log(b)
    }
)
```

I recreated it in python and found out the result should be

```
{
  "UserID": 1,
  "UserName": "User",
  "RobuxBalance": 0, 
  "ThumbnailUrl": "https://tr.rbxcdn.com/3decdb8a572d4c9ff206ce4984f1579e/352/352/Avatar/Png",
  "IsAnyBuildersClubMember": false,
  "IsPremium": false
}
```

I would just use python, but I prefer NodeJS.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried `'Cookie': '.ROBLOSECURITY=' + input` in your `headers` object?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I send cookie using NodeJs request GET module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33347685/how-can-i-send-cookie-using-nodejs-request-get-module)

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek unfortunately that didnt work. The way I can tell is if it returns a full page source instead of a JSON table which is does not return sadly.

Comment: @DonFoumare also what you linked sadly didnt work either.

Comment: @Arilis, if you want to send a cookie with a GET request **to the server** you should pass it in the `Cookie` header: `'Cookie': 'ROBLOSECURITY=THISISTHECOOKIE'`. If you want to send it in a respond **to a client** use the `'Set-Cookie': 'ROBLOSECURITY=THISISTHECOOKIE'`

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case, you must use :

```js
cookieJar.setCookie(cookieName, input);
```

before making the request.